# How to deploy spring boot war in Tomcat in Docker container?

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:9
COPY ATI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ATI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

here is my docker logs
[image]

but no matter which path I type, an error appears
[image]
Tell me, is there something wrong with my dockerfile, or is my program not deployed in docker?

Comment: share your DockerFile code

Comment: Your war file was deployed correctly, but the url (the path, specifically) that you use to access it is not correct. Unfortunately I have no idea what the correct path would be based on the information in this question.

Comment: @bipin it's at the top of the question

Comment: @f1sh sorry missed that

Comment: @bipin FROM tomcat:9
            COPY ATI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ATI-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.war
            CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

Comment: Have you considered generating an executable Spring Boot JAR and running that instead (in a Java image)

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel
Yes, I tried, but I ran into an error : Unrecognized option: - jar

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. But maybe I should have studied this question better

Comment: package it as jar using spring boots own tomcat. no point messing with war and another tomcat, unless you need to. build it on for example amazoncorretto image, so your jar will execute properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a result, I just deployed the jar in a docker container using dockerfile FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY ATI.jar  ATI.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/ATI.jar"]   the main thing in application.properties in spring.datasource.url is to specify the correct url, I specified the IP of my computer  which I learned with the help of the team ip a in linux

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile is correct.

You need to check which version of JDK was used to build your WAR file.

If the JDK version isn't supported by Tomcat 9, your application wont run. Tomcat 9 would support JDK 8

Refer the below link and update your JDK or Tomcat version accordingly
https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: thanks, I looked and I have version 11

Comment: Then you should use Tomcat 10.X